# Android add fadeIn and fadeOut to translate animation

Tags: android, animation

this animation work fine for me when i try to use that to open activity from right to left, but it doesn't support `fadeIn` and i can't add that,

translate animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

alpha animation:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
```

i try to use this below solution, but it dosn't work correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:duration="500"
           android:fromAlpha="0.0"
           android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
           android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score -1):

Fade in and fade out does not need translate animation you can directly use alpha animation like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
  <alpha
      android:fromAlpha="0.1"
      android:toAlpha="1.0"
      android:duration="2000"
      />
</set>
```

Fade in will have alfha .1 to 1 so that it can fade in.

for uses see details

[Fade in & Fade out animation]

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html

http://nineoldandroids.com/

Example which can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to have move from right to left with alpha animation, can i have this ability?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
          android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
          android:duration="300" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
          android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:fillAfter="true"
           android:duration="300" />
```

and inside your activity do the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```